# Merging multiple gcov files into one

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, gcov

I am using the SonarQube CFamily plugin for static analysis and code coverage. This particular plugin relies on .gcov files to create the coverage report (the free CXX plugin uses a cobertura XML report generated by gcovr and **neither** plugin supports lcov .info files)

We have 100's of tests which are run in parallel on distributed servers (it would take 12 hrs to run them all on the same box) thus I am looking for a way to merge the generated .gcov files into one final file and have SonarQube scan those files.

Is this possible ?

Comment: I was not able to find a answer but I did find a python module that converts lcov .info files to cobertura XML  and I was able to work around the issue that way. https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to merge coverage data from two executables with gcov/gcovr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833081/is-it-possible-to-merge-coverage-data-from-two-executables-with-gcov-gcovr)