# Combining C++ Coverage Results from Parallel stages in a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gcov, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline{
   stages
   {
      stage ("Compile Everything") {/**/} // Code coverage flags turned on
                                          // Stashes compiled test binaries. 
      stage ("Parallel Tests"){
         parallel{
            stage ("Run Tests A-L") {/**/} // These stages unstash and run groups of tests,
            stage ("Run Tests L-Z") {/**/} // causing coverage files to be created.
                                           // I analyze those coverage files via
                                           // gcovr and stash the results as xml.
         }
      }

      stage ("Combine and Publish Coverage") {/**/} // Here I can unstash all of the xml
                                                    // code coverage files, but don't know
                                                    // how to combine them.
   }
}
```

In that final stage, "Combine and Publish Coverage" is it possible to combine all of the xml files created by gcovr?

Has anyone solved the problem of testing in parallel and combining coverage results in another way entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution isn't as elegant as I'd like, but the best I can come up with.

Use `lcov` instead of `gcovr` to initially generate the coverage reports. This creates `.info` files which `lcov` is capable of combining down to a single `.info` file.

Unstash all `.info` files from previous stages, then use `lcov -a` to combine them into a single `.info` file. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35120225/4347243))

Next, use the [`lcov-to-cobertura`](https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml) converter to convert this `.info` file into an xml file which can be reported to SonarQube.

Comment: Better accept the solution so as to close any further discussion.